# Connecting to an OBDC database from a Xamarin IOS / Visual Studio Mac solution

Tags: xamarin.ios, odbc

First, I am just getting starting with VS/Mac and Xamarin in general.

This question concerns accessing database servers.

I am attempting to port existing corporate applications to the iOS environment.  At the outset of a "Hello World" type app in order to get used to the environment I successfully added a reference to "System.Data". This lead me to easily exposing SQL Server connection options via "System.Data.SQLClient" .  No problem so far.

Another requirement of our corporate apps is to connect to a Progress database and the previous method was to utilize a reference to "System.Data.odbc".  This is my issue.  "System.Data.odbc" does not exist in this environment.

I can switch to a web service if necessary, but I would like to port as much of the original code as possible to start with.

Also, these are closed applications in the sense that they are only available on our corporate network.

In a Windows Forms application i would create a connection similar to this:

```
odbcConnection cn = new ODBC.connection;
cn.connectionString = blah blah;
cn.open();
```

And so on...

To those that have developed corporate data access apps in both Windows Forms and Visual Studio/Mac/Xamarin I simply ask:  "What am I missing?"

Thanks to each responder in advance.

Earl

Comment: generally, you should never connect from a client, particularly a mobile client, directly to a database server.  You should have an intermediary layer, typically a webservice, sitting between them.

Comment: Haven't done this, but I'd wager you should be using base classes in your shared code (DbConnection instead of SqlConnection), and in the platform-specific code inject the appropriate type for the system.